# Jahia : maxlength constraint on a node property

Tags: properties, jahia

I've been looking for a few hours now for this simple question: how can I add a maxlength constraint on a jahia node text property?

What I've tried so far in the studio:

[image: Jahia Studio example]

I also tried seeting it directly in the definition.cnd, but cannot find any example or documentation about the max length of a text.

The property is a String TextArea, with no other specific property (but the maxlength I wanna add...)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a regexp as a constraint. Typically your definition could be like this:

```
[jnt:test2] > jnt:content, jmix:basicContent
 - test2 (string, textarea) < '.{0,250}'
```

If you use the UI from the studio, you just need to add `.{0,250}` in the *Value constraints* input.

And you can also handle the error message in your resource bundle file by adding such key/value:

```
jnt_test2.test2.constraint.error.message=Please enter a valuer smaller than 250 chars
```